# Laziest way to check number constraints

Tags: php

This question is born out of pure laziness and the desire to do more with less code.

Say I have a variable `$x` which needs to be greater than 0 and less than 12, what is the fastest (least amount of code written) way to check. Is there a faster way than this.

```
if($x < 0 || $x > 12) {
   die("invalid x value");
}
```

It would be nice (and I think some languages have it) to do this:

```
if(0 > $x > 12) {
   die("invalid x value");
}
```

Very curious to see if there is some PHP magic I am missing out on.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i don't understand, also its in beta?

Comment: Your question is a better fit for CG in my opinion.

Comment: oh ok, I will have a look there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter_var as a native PHP function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php But I don't find it any better, as you will need to pass an array with min and max range, which is not fast, nor short.

Maybe a user-defined function for this will fit? Yes, you will need to write the code once, but only once.

```
function between($value, $from, $to) {
    if ($value < $from || $value > $to) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The function return false, if the value is less than the min bound, or greater than the max bound. Otherwise it returns true. So if you need to stop you script, if the value is NOT between, you would need to ask for the false response `if(!between...`

So you only call it this way:

```
$x = 14;
if(!between($x, 0, 12)) {
    die("invalid x value");
}
```

Output:

> invalid x value

if, for example your $x is `5` and you want to check if it's between, and if it is - to continue the script, you ask for the `true` response.

```
if(between($x, 0, 12)
```

Comment: Your `between` function can be reduced to simply `return !($value < $from || $value > $to);` or `return $value >= $from && $value <= $to;`.